# How to create multiple rooted JSON for ExtJS store?

Tags: json, extjs, grid, store

I want to create a JSON string on server side with 2 root. I am using ExtJS 3.2. I want to use first root for load data to grid and the second one is to fill a form with different data.
I am creating JSON string on server side like this;

```
{
    metaData: {
        "idProperty": "reportID", 
        "root": "data", 
        "successProperty": "success"
    }, 
    "success": true, 
    "data": [
    {
        "ID": 1, 
        "name": "Jon", 
        "surname": "Doe"
    }]
}
```

Let's assume second **root** name is **summary** and second **idProperty** is **summaryID**. How can I implement this and where can I add summary data?
Thx all.

Comment: we can use, 
`{
    "success": true, 
    "root1": [
      {
          "ID": 1, 
          "name": "Jon", 
          "surname": "Doe"
      },
   {
          "ID": 2, 
          "name": "Jane", 
          "surname": "Doe"
      }
  ],
 "root2": [
      {
          "ID": 1, 
          "name": "Jack", 
          "surname": "Brown"
      },
   {
          "ID": 2, 
          "name": "Chris", 
          "surname": "Brown"
      }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automagic for you are willing to do.i had the same issue on [this project](https://github.com/mehdifanai/medalyser) and i figured out how to create multiple stores automatically from a JSON response.put the following code before your grids are loaded.in extjs4,i put the following code in app.js so the stores will be created when the app is initialized.The stores will be created automatically,dependent on what the JSON returns:

```
    Ext.Ajax
                    .request({
                        url : './account/getadminstores',
                        callback : function(options, success, response) {
                            var json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            var adminStores = new Array();
                            // setup and intitialize on the fly stores
                            for ( var key1 in json) {
                                var storeFields = new Array();
                                for ( var key2 in json[key1]) {// if
                                    // (i==1){break;}
                                    // console.log(key2);
                                    for ( var key3 in json[key1][key2]) {
                                        storeFields.push(key3);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                ;
                                Ext.define('MA.store.' + key1, {
                                    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
                                    fields : storeFields,
                                    storeId : key1,
                                    id : 'MA.store.' + key1,
                                    data : json[key1],
                                proxy: {
                                    type: 'ajax',
                                    url : './account/getadminstores',
                                    reader: {
                                        type: 'json',
                                        root: key1
                                    }
                                },
                                autoLoad: true
                                });
                                Ext.create('MA.store.' + key1);
                            }
                            ;
```

Created stores for your case would be `MA.store.root1`and `MA.store.root2`which MA is your apps namespace(and you should change it to whatever your app namespace is).This code is for extjs4 and you might need  some modifications to make it work in older versions.Hope it helps.

Comment: I can not vote up because it wants 15 reputations :S But I accepted your answer.

Comment: Thanks.I got through lots of pain to write this king of pain.its GNU/GPl licensed and you can use it wherever you like.